# yf.Ticker("MSFT").info doesn't provide information about "industry" and "sector", any idea of other commands to get this in python using yfinance API?

Tags: python, api, yfinance

I used to use this to get info about a ticker:

```
tx = yf.Ticker("MSFT")  
indst=tx.info.get('industry')
sect=tx.info.get('sector')
st=tx.info.get('state')
```

However, none of these ('industry','sector','state') exist anymore in the tx.info object.
Is there another way to get this info about a given ticker using yahoo finance API in python?

I've tried other commands as
`tx.fast_info` and `tx.get_history_metadata()`
and none include info related to 'industry','sector'.